# django remote user (trusted connection on IIS)

Tags: python, django, iis

I set up django for a trusted connection (remote user) on IIS but on the client side, it is always asking for the user to type the username and password on a pop up alert from browser. Does anyone knows how can I solve it?

See the screenshot from the browser below:

[image]

Comment: make sure you disabled windows authentication in iis for the Django site and enable anonymous authentication.

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal, This is the opposite what I want. Actually I need the trusted connection and get the remote user. The question is why it is asking for user and password. I believe it is something related to SSL certificate but I could not figure out yet.

Comment: could you share steps to reproduce issue?

Comment: It is only open the browser and try to access the server ip. I can share part of the code but you have to be more specific what you want to see. I am sure the application is 100% set up correctly. If there is an issue, it is on the IIS side and I am almost 100% sure it is related to SSL certificate. I have it, but somehow it is not being considered.

Comment: how you set the trusted connection in iis. and iis windows authentication will only work with AD domain.